# OpenGL and the PR2

Tags: ros, visualization, pr2, gui, opengl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone suggest how to create an OpenGL function (no OGRE dependencies) that renders the PR2?  That is, I hope to construct a function that looks like:

void openGLRenderPR2 (JointState);

I imagine this would be of use to many people who are using visualization tools outside of rviz (and without OGRE dependencies).

Thanks!

Mike

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30970/opengl-and-the-pr2/) by [mfleder](https://answers.ros.org/users/828/mfleder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2012-04-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is actually not that easy. You first need to read in the robot description from urdf, there is a library for doing so. Then you to load all meshes. rviz used to use [assimp](http://ros.org/wiki/assimp) for doing that. Finally, you need a tf listener to get the current pose of all links specified in the urdf.

I implemented the functionality for rendering the PR2 in common lisp, stack cram_physics and I think Bosch's [pr2_camera_self_filter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_camera_self_filter) contains some code for rendering the PR2 in C++.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1